# Can we filter questions by reputation?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, search, filtering

There seems to be a deluge of questions by folks with rep of 1-10. Many of these questions are "homework" or questions that are annoying to me, like "please read my 500 line script and tell me what’s wrong with it"

Is there a way to filter questions by reputation?

Comment: been a year and i still dont see any change, still lots of questions being asked by lazy people where a simple link to the manual page would suffice.
why was this feature declined?

Comment: @Quamis: Agreed.

Comment: With reviews this may have slightly improved. Too bad the close queue surpassed 73k...

Comment: This is a completely valid question. I find myself coming to this site less and less because of the barrage of entry level questions. I definitely don't want to discourage people from asking, but if I want to answer questions from seasoned programmers it's difficult to sift through. There should be a way to filter. Maybe based on badge achievement.

Comment: And I'll add this: there are many times that people answer a question only to receive a "thanks, that worked" comment. No upvote, not marked as the answer. And these are inevitably from new people that don't understand the etiquette of stack overflow. Not sure how to mitigate it but it happens.

Answer (score 22):

There are also a lot of new users with good questions who haven't had the chance to gain rep yet. We already have closing, downvoting, flagging, deleting and editing. Those are in place to clear up spam, unclear, offensive, closed and poorly-worded questions, respectively.

Votes, flags and closing is a much better indication of a question's worth than the reputation of the one who asked it. I can name a lot of high-rep users who consistently ask bad questions, and I've seen lots of good questions asked by brand new users. A filter won't solve anything.

Comment: Completely agree there. We were all there once..

Comment: Perhaps they should get their first 10 rep by actually answering a question first.

Comment: That's a foolish theory, Byron. The vast majority of users find SO because they're trying to find information, not because they're itching to teach people computer science.

Comment: "I can name a lot of high-rep users who consistently ask bad questions, and I've seen lots of good questions asked by brand new users." - there are always *exceptions*. so what? are you saying there's no *statistical* quality difference between the questions of those user groups? it scares me the way you quickly jump to the conclusion "A filter won't solve anything."

Answer (score 15):

If a significant number of the people who actually answer questions were to do this, it would seriously impact the number of new people coming to SO to ask questions.  If people don't get their questions answered, they won't be back.  Overall, I think it would degrade the utility of SO in unacceptable ways.

Comment: I don't think a significant number of "answerers" would do this. This type of esoteric behavior usually doesn't take the community over.

Comment: Tvan, I completely agree. @Jonathan Why would we implement a feature that we *don't* want users to use? Every feature must be designed assuming that many people will adopt it. As soon as someone starts using it and mentioned how great it is, others will use it, and *never realize what they're missing*. It is a way of stating "StackOverflow is full. We don't need any more new users".

Comment: They will come back since whenever they google something they will come across SO. Not getting any replies will tell them they are doing something wrong. And they will hopefully learn.

Comment: Unfortunately, this shows the conflict between SO being a business and being a service to its users.

Answer (score 14):

This is one of the most toxic ideas I've witnessed here.

Stack Exchange is designed to be a place where anyone can *meaningfully* contribute to the site with *zero* buy-in. You can, should you choose to, create a question without even logging in (on most sites).
We **want** this behaviour, because it allows the generation of all the rich content we have. We want to set the bar to entry to be quite low, because once a user arrives and finds it welcoming, we want them to stay.

Remember, **Low rep *does not* equal low skill!**

Low rep means that they have not been around Stack Exchange very long.
The following is a selection of users whose questions would get filtered. (AFAIK)

- [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/)
- [Charles Petzold](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507041609/http://www.amazon.com/Charles-Petzold/e/B000APETXO/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1)
- [Steve McConnell](https://stevemcconnell.com/)
- [Paul Graham](http://www.paulgraham.com/lisp.html)
- Bill Gates
- Steve Jobs

Those are just a few. And I, for one, would **really** want to read what they have to say, even though they have no reputation on Stack Overflow.

There are millions of other people out there with zero reputation, and I think the assumption that their low reputation means that they have no value is offensive.

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution!

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162190/unanswered-questions-from-users-with-reputation-100

This is for Unanswered questions from users with reputation >= 100.

It should be easy to modify to suit your tastes.

Answer (score 8):

This request was declined for a good reason, offering a bounty won't change it.

**These sites are not about people. Judge the content, not the person who posted it.** Filtering by reputation makes absolutely no sense, there are bad questions asked by users with 500 of reputation, and great questions asked by new users every day.

Such thing would only lead to make it harder for new people to get answers, even if their questions are great. It's already hard enough to get attention, with your question staying on front page for about 20 minutes max, don't increase the problem.

Elitism is the plague of all computer related help sites, and I'm pretty sure we don't want that on the trilogy.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is no for two reasons:

1. New people will find it harder to "get into" the community, leading to a clique.
2. Existing users will push even harder to boost their reputation, which may create undesirable results (e.g. questions only aimed at rep-boosting).

Answer (score 1):

#### Hidden feature

I don't know if it's really hidden, but adding `/?tab=recommended` will give you this filter option.

I think it's working only on *stackoverflow.com*.

[image]

*https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&minRep=50*

Comment: They've destroyed that feature!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to have this feature both for questions and answers.

Maybe for questions it should be part of a "complex" search function while for answers it could be enabled only for questions that have more that X answers.

Comment: Who's to say a new user has poorer quality of answers

Comment: I found a way to do it. Check my answer here.