# Can we get the asker on the front page instead the most recent changer?

Tags: feature-request, homepage

This may be wrong of me but when I'm scanning a list of questions looking for the best stuff, I'm more interested in who's asking than who made the last comment. Questions asked by high-rep users are simply more likely to yield fruit than those by more junior users.

Is there any way we can get the asker's id displayed with the questions on the front page?

Comment: I know this is a dup, but don't have it handy.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/can-we-filter-questions-by-reputation/3990#3990

Comment: @Jon, something must be wrong with your link, it doesn't have anything to do with who shows on the front page with a question.

Comment: @Lance: You're right, it doesn't. But it does give a partial solution to filtering questions based on the last editor's rep, which is partially what's being asked here.

Answer (score 3):

The front page shows *active* questions; it makes perfect sense to me to show the name who was active last (and note the clickable "xx minutes ago" too).

Seems to me you might want to use https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest et al, rather than http://meta.stackoverflow.com and the like.

Comment: arjan is correct, pick a different view, and the question owner will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

But, if a high-rep user is active on a question, isn't it likely that they have added considerable value to any question?

Also, you are implying that questions asked by low-rep users have less value than questions asked by high-rep users.  I think that that assumption is incorrect in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I am implying questions asked by high-rep users are generally of higher quality than those asked by low-rep users. And high-rep answers are generally better than low-rep answers. Perhaps that is politically incorrect, but nevertheless I think it reflects reality.

If rep doesn't matter then why display any user id at all with the questions on the front page?

Comment: @I. J. K. High rep users start out as low rep users.  However, you are right in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

As Justin [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56590/can-we-get-the-asker-on-the-front-page-instead-the-most-recent-changer/56591#56591), questions asked by low-rep users don't necessarily have less value than high rep users.

The best equalizer is looking at the [hot tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot). This shows questions with the highest "interest" within the last few days.

If you're curious about how the "interest" score is calculated, Jeff spelled out the whole formula [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected/4789#4789).