# Is there a way to filter questions based on the reputation of the asker?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, filtering

Sometimes when browsing on SO, I'd like to filter out the questions from users with less than say, 1k reputation. Users with higher rep usually seem to be asking questions that are more challenging to solve and require more thought or research than other users, where often there is a preponderance of be badly-formatted code or horribly worded questions.

Nothing against the latter users, and I try my best to help them, but sometimes I just want to look for a change of scenery. I'm not necessary going after the high-bounty or really-upvoted questions; I'd just like to see "normal" questions posted by high-rep users. Is there any way to apply a filter in this way?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Can we filter questions by reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3987/172661).

Answer (score 4):

Overall reputation of the OP doesn't have much to do with how challenging or difficult a question will be to ask.

I have most of my 16K rep from the Faceook and PHP tags... Just wait till I ask a question about a technology that I'm just starting to learn.

What about an experienced programmer who has just recently discovered the site? They might have a very interesting and challenging question but still only have <1K reputation...

Comment: Just because it isn't perfectly correlated doesn't mean there's no correlation. I bet you when you are asking about a new technology, that you will have done your research beforehand and asked a cohesive, straightforward question. On other hand, if someone is an experienced programmer, good for them...their question is apt to get lost in the flood of low-quality questions anyway.

Comment: I think the main factor is that experienced users have learned when and how to ask a good question. I was a seasoned programmer when I first joined StackOverflow. I'm not particularly proud of my own first questions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so, but great idea.  It would also be handy to be able to search for questions from users below a certain rep.  Maybe a format something along the lines of:

- user-rep-min: 100
- user-rep-max: 1000