# RSS feeds should include metadata

Tags: feature-request, feed

RSS feed should include question metadata (tags, author rep, &c) so that it is easier to filter downstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags *are* included in the rss feed for a question.  Here is a snippet from the RSS feed for this question:

```
<category scheme="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/202721/tags" 
    term="feature-request"/>
<category scheme="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/202721/tags" 
    term="rss"/>
```

That's in `//feed/entry`.

Comment: how about author rep?

Comment: @sds It's not really a property of the question itself, so it doesn't really make sense there, but it could potentially go on the user's RSS feed.  Really though [we don't really want users filtering questions based on the author's rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/can-we-filter-questions-by-reputation).