# Additional/advanced search/filter options

Tags: feature-request, search

There seem to be a lot of requests for more advanced search/filter options, but I don't see any for these items. Can we get some options to filter out questions by users within/outside a certain rep range (I'd like to filter out < 500) and/or questions within/outside an upvote/downvote range (I'd like to filter out <= -2 downvotes).

In fact, why doesn't SE have a dynamic query feature that allows users to query any attribute we like? I wrote one myself about a year ago that leveraged OData to convert a query string of binary/unary/lambda expressions into a .NET expression tree to be used as a predicate for an Entity Framework query. One code base handled all future queries and never had to be refactored if I added new properties to my entities.

Failing new search features, I was going to write my own userscript to do this based on the HTML, but it wouldn't work with question that are edited as shown below. Question was asked by UserXXXXXXXX, but edited by someone else, so that someone else's name shows in the main question index.

[image]

Comment: You can query [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) for that, assuming you don't mind its data might be stale up to 7 days. The [OData endpoints have been disabled on SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247931/hide-the-broken-odata-link-in-data-explorer/254120#254120). You don't have to create the user script yourself, it is already there: https://stackapps.com/questions/7496/reputation-based-filter-for-search-results and if you want to query a posts state, consider using the API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/can-we-filter-questions-by-reputation and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152353/filter-questions-by-user-reputation

Comment: @rene Perhaps, then, it would be useful to be able to customize the filters to add user-selected SEDE queries to it? If you frequently run a particular query, you could click on an added filter link that would execute it against the site you're currently viewing.

Comment: @JasonBassford that would still need a userscript as SEDE is open source and the Q/A core isn't and so far I'm unaware of an intent to open up the Q/A core for external integrations.

Comment: @rene I may have come across those questions, but they are outdated (one is almost 10 years old). Also, 7 days is probably too stale. Query would need to be against current data. The API seems nice, but returns raw data and the userscript link you referenced calls that API. I am talking about a userscript that removes HTML elements from the main question index by inspecting values in elements with `class="reputation-score"` and `class="votes"`. What would be nice is a UI feature that lets me build my query by selecting fields and operators from a list and entering values with keyboard.

Comment: This [old feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax) (`status-completed`) leads (eventually, 3 clicks away) to [advanced search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). While "Rep" is missing from the list the OP invites new requests.